# Git push to Azure failing (RPC failed)

Tags: git, azure

I've been deploying to Azure via Git for several months with no major issues, but now I've seem to hit an error I can't get past.

I made a new Azure Web Site to create a separate preview link for a project in active development. I set up Git publishing on the new site and tried pushing the same project repo that I am using on other Azure Web Sites. Every push attempt, however, fails:

```
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've tried pushing a much smaller commit (just an empty text file), and the push goes through fine.

I'm fairly certain that this error is due to my repo size (~50mb). Since this is a fresh push, it needs to transfer the full repo size instead of the incremental pushes I've been doing for months.

I've tried increasing my `http.postBuffer`:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But my push still fails.

Does Azure needs to increase the size of the POST requests it receives? Or is there another fix I am unaware of?

Any suggestions?

**Update:**
This is a known issue. It (so far) has been narrowed down to an issue with the compbination of Mac and https. You can follow the issue threads on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuregit/thread/2edc314d-8e18-4d12-843e-92d6de6c3c3d/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/171).

Comment: Just to add a bit of info. I had the same issue (except HTTP code 500) and the postBuffer fix made things work properly for me.

Comment: That http.postBuffer fix worked for me. I kept getting the error running for PowerShell in Parallels on my iMac.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that this isn't something you can fix on your own. I've also two websites where git push has been working fine this morning but now I get the same error. Let's wait and see what happens...

Comment: Meaning this is a hiccup in the service? Or that I need to get someone at Microsoft to fix something?

Comment: I think this is a failure of the service. You can open a thread in the official support forum (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/category/windowsazureplatformctp) but I think they will fix it soon anyway.

Comment: Looks like a hiccup in the service, as Daniel stated open a thread or wait for support to fix it, it's still in "Preview" :)

Answer (score 0):

**My Environment**

Windows 7 running in VMWare Fusion on a Macbook Pro running El Capitan (ver. 10.11.5).
Using Git Bash as my client.
Azure App Services as my remote git destinations.

**The Problem**

I have two environments running as Web App (App Services) on Azure for the same site (a staging and a production environment).

When I push to the staging environment via git push , I have no problems.

When I push to the production via git push , I get the following error message:

```
RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**The Solution**

After reading @redhotvengeance's Update, I fired up my Windows 7 desktop and pulled down the source code to it, then pushed to my Azure production environment (the deployment that was failing) and it completed the push without any issues.

It would seem that it might be an Azure / Mac issue of some kind.

Comment: 4 years later, and it appears that this still hasn't been fixed. Disappointing.

Comment: 6 years later, and it appears that this still hasn't been fixed. Very Disappointing.

Comment: 9 years later, and it appears that this still hasn't been fixed. Very very Disappointing.