# Git push error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal

Tags: git, github, windows-7-x64

While doing git push, I receive this error:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': Newbie
Password for 'https://Newbie@github.com':
Counting objects: 11507, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8210/8210), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11506/11506), 21.75 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11506 (delta 2213), reused 11504 (delta 2211)
efrror: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I also tried doing: git config http.postBuffer 524288000, but still error..
Also tried: git config --global http.postBuffer 2M by referring on [git push error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005259/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-0)

Please can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same error. By using the GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 I got the following extra details: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054

Comment: @Newbie ,have you solved the above problem,I am also facing same error.

Answer (score 106):

Look here: https://flyingtomoon.com/2011/04/12/git-push-is-failed-due-to-rpc-failure-result56/

The problem is most likely because your git buffer is too low.

You will need to increase Git’s HTTP buffer by setting the git config var “http.postBuffer” to 524288000.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: This worked fantastically! After this issue was resolved, we ran into a different one (we're using Bonovo Git Server). It was resolved changing what's stated in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456025/rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-404). So, odds are some of you may have the same issue, so I thought of posting it here.

Comment: I had a similar problem on Windows 7. After hours of googling, comming accross this post and doubling the buffer size, I discovered it was my antivirus software that was causing the issue

Comment: Showing not in a Git Directory, what to do?

Comment: @ManabKumarMal add the global tag to the git command `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

Comment: This worked :-) Note: navigate to the root folder of the GIT project that  causes the above mentioned issue

Comment: I am MAC User and it works fine for me. **git config http.postBuffer 524288000**

Answer (score 24):

Increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Comment: This was the complete answer. Increase your buffer size to maximum file size on your repo. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 12):

This error was caused by my corporate Firewall.

Comment: This is quite frustrating though, not sure what I can do if the policy is there and not able to change.

Answer (score 8):

I faced a similar issue. When I was trying to push my branch to remote, I was seeing this error: >**error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54**

In my case, this issue was caused due to a proxy that I was connected to. I disconnected the VPN connection and tried to push my changes again and that worked.

Comment: Refresh (Disconnect/Reconnect) your VPN. It worked for me.

Comment: I disconnected my vpn. it worked. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try re-initializing your git repository:
git init

Comment: This actually worked and I am curious, so i have questions...what triggered the error even though the repository was already initialized? In my case I was trying to push to a new repository.

Answer (score 4):

It will work after increasing Git’s `HTTP` buffer by setting the `git config` var `http.postBuffer` to `524288000`.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Answer (score 4):

Poor network connection was the issue for me. Check your internet strength.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I was cloning a git repo that was taking a long time. I went to do something else and my computer went to sleep, terminating the connection. Turning off auto sleep on my computer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a very similar issue, though I was deploying to an Azure Web App via a git push. I received this error:

```
RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The solution for me was to change my deployment environment from a Macbook to a Windows desktop. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294072/29613) for full details.

Comment: Hmm...someone care to tell me why you just down voted this answer? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try building git using openssl libraries. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833932/git-error-rpc-failed-result-55-http-code-200/25176589#25176589). You may have to compile git in Windows. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, maybe this code is working

```
git config http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating curl to latest and it was awesome, it worked for me