# ERROR on git push origin master - error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10053 fatal:

Tags: git, curl, git-commit, github-for-windows

I am facing the below error while pushing my changes to origin/master.
error: **RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10053
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg2ri.png)**

I followed the similar error page, [Git push error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952683/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-fatal-the-remote-end-hun) but of no help. Solution provided on this page is not working for me.
Any hints are highly appreciated!!

Comment: Windows error 10053 is "connection aborted". This is the system's way of telling you that the server (not your own computer, but the *other* end of the connection) is saying "go away, stop bothering me". You will have to figure out why. A good first step would be to figure out *who*. Then find someone in charge of the "who", and ask *them*.

Comment: @torek thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mostly it's your crapy sad internet connection.