# Cannot push binary file in git

Tags: git, github

I have a binary file of size ~11MB stored in repo. Now I updated this file locally and want to push the new version.

When I push it I see following:

```
$  git push --set-upstream origin feature/new-win-installer

git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Counting objects: 291, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (231/231), done.
Writing objects:  20% (60/291), 34.49 MiB | 135.00 KiB/s
```

It's already 3 times bigger than original file so I aborted it. I have no other files in this commit.

What's wrong here? How could it be avoided?

---

I tried to delete the file completely, but I'm unable to do that too:

```
$  git push --set-upstream origin feature/new-win-installer
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Counting objects: 290, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (230/230), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (290/290), 115.55 MiB | 215.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 290 (delta 110), reused 136 (delta 33)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Anything I can do without mixed reset to the point before I added the file?

Comment: If the push failed then you're better off, because versioning large binary files in Git is generally a really bad idea.  Unless maybe if that binary is an image from your site or something, you are better off versioning it outside of Git.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but 11mb is not a big file. IIRC github limit is ~100mb, which I'm defenitly not going to push.

Comment: Remember that you're not just pushing the files but the commit history as well. Git can't record single-line changes on a large binary file, so perhaps it's just making a copy. Git is based on line changes.

Comment: @DanWilson hmm, so if I remove the file and then add new one then it should work? Going to try. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Read Dan's comment, because each time the version changes, boom!  You basically have to store the new version from scratch.  Unless you are _certain_ that you'll never change that file, 11MB can easily grow to 100MB+.

Comment: If you only want to send 11MB to the server then you'll actually have to purge commits where you changed the file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git).

Comment: @DanWilson sounds great, however, I neved did it so I was just unaware of it. Going to check how it could be performed. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a commonly-used command, because you almost *never* want to lose commit history.

Comment: @DanWilson I actually don't want to lose the whole history too, I just want to update (or at least *remove*) this file in (from) git. I pushed a commit where I delete it, but I see the same behavior. I didn't think it's so hard for him to store binaries.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a dupe. Linked issue talks about *gigabytes*, when mine is only 11mb. Git should easily handle files of such size.

Comment: Have you looked at similar errors: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46232906/8293848