# API causes "Curl error: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054"

Tags: php, azure, curl, openssl

This is **not** related to `homestead` nor `vagrant` nor `laravel`.

I have an app service running on `PHP` 7.3 on a Windows Azure server.

Here's the code I'm running in relation to my `cURL` call:

```
$resCurl = curl_init();

$url_API = 'https://example.com/api/someMethod';

curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array( 'Content-type: APPLICATION/JSON; CHARSET=UTF-8' ) );
curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonRequest );

curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_API );
curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$resultAPI = curl_exec( $resCurl );
```

When this is executed, I keep on generating this error:

> Curl error: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Running the command prompt, I can execute `php -i` to see if `openssl` has a directory it's reading from as well a file mentioned:

[image: Open SSL Version and configuration]

I've already checked the directory and downloaded the most up-to-date `cacert.pem` file from here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

I DO NOT want to solve this issue through turning off SSL verification by setting my `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false.

Any advice?

**UPDATE:**

I hardcoded options for both `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` and `CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE`:

```
curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'D:\home\site\cert\cacert.pem');
curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM' );
```

And the error is different now:

> unable to set private key file: 'D:\home\site\cert\cacert.pem' type
>   PEM

I would upload a private key, but there are no private keys for this public cacert.

Comment: Error `10054` means "Connection reset by peer" indicating there is some kind of connection issue going on between the client and server. Perhaps interrupted by a firewall or routing issue.

Comment: @Drew010 you wer right it was a firewall issue, post an answer and I'll accept if Jack Jia doesn't get to it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, everything is OK.

My environment:

1. Windows 10 1809
2. PHP 7.3 (7.3.11)
3. cacert from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

---

Code:

```
    $resCurl = curl_init();

    $url_API = 'https://example.com/api/someMethod';
    $jsonRequest = '{"a":"aaa"}';
    curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array( 'Content-type: APPLICATION/JSON; CHARSET=UTF-8' ) );
    curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonRequest );

    curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_API );
    curl_setopt( $resCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $resultAPI = curl_exec( $resCurl );
    $print_r($resultAPI)
```

Result:

[image]

---

Suggestion

So, basically this part of code is fine.

As you said that it is not related to homestead nor vagrant nor laravel. So, it is most likely a network issue. Maybe you can try to restart the Azure server.

---

### **Update**

**Confirmed by @LatentDenis, he finally found that the problem was caused by the firewall, which can give us a clue to narrow down similiar issues.**

Comment: Thanks for testing on your end, I went ahead and updated my question at the end - do you know anything about the new error being generated?

Comment: I realize the issue, the resource I was attempting to access had our IPs blocked. If you revise your answer to say account for blocks on the server (firewall issues) I'll accept!

Comment: @LatentDenis Your case would point out a direction to others who have similiar issues. Updated in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Version 2.0.2 Installer Version.
[Download](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.0.2/vagrant_2.0.2_x86_64.msi)

and other solution you can found on this below link :

[error rpc failed curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232906/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno)