# getting this when trying to clone a repo using git

Tags: git, github

error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0
error: 7889 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232906/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno

Comment: @AniketAgarwal https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Answer (score 2):

When you use HTTPS, that's a tunneled HTTP connection inside a TLS tunnel.  One of the features TLS provides is integrity: that is, an attacker cannot modify the data without being detected.

The message "decryption failed or bad record mac" means that someone or something (that is, a person or some device between your system and GitHub), did indeed tamper with the data, and as a result, the only thing to do is abort the connection.  If OpenSSL didn't abort the connection in this case, you'd receive data that was corrupt or malicious.

There are a bunch of possibilities here.  If you're using a proxy, non-default antivirus or firewall, or a TLS MITM device on your network, that is probably the problem.  Those devices are known to have a variety of problems in their TLS implementations, some of which impact security.  You should try without them installed, or use a different network.

It's also possible that you have a bad network card or some sort of broken network device between you that is causing problems.  For example, [some users have reported known breakage with AT&T](https://www.reddit.com/r/ATT/comments/k0b7tf/massive_issue_on_ssltls_connections/), and other ISPs may have other problems.

You could also try cloning over SSH and see if that works.  TLS middleboxes like the kinds I mentioned above won't be able to tamper with an SSH connection, and so that may be more reliable for you.  Of course, if there's a network problem, it will also likely impact SSH, but at least it will be obvious to you that it's a network problem in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seemed to be a connection problem. Fixed this by raising the buffer

Comment: `http.postBuffer` has no effect on clones.  [See the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) for more details.  What you were seeing is some sort of transient issue if that helped.