# Error when Trying to push local repository to github

Tags: git, github, git-push

Hi guys I am new to git/ github I tried to push my repo to github but keeps giving me this error although i followed all instruction to push it to my github.
The error is :

```
$ git push --all origin
Enumerating objects: 979, done.
Counting objects: 100% (979/979), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (939/939), done.
Werror: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (979/979), 3.34 GiB | 2.72 MiB/s, done.
Total 979 (delta 169), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

can somebody with git knowledge help a beginner in git please.

Comment: Have you tried these?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232906/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno

Comment: I did the config yesterday when I tried to search the solution of the problem but I keep getting the error.

Comment: What operating system are you on and what version of Git are you running?

Comment: on Windows and git version is 2.33.1-64-bit

Comment: It seems this error is cause by a bad https connection. Try using ssh to connect to your repo. https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh
I would suggest cloning, making a small change, and attempt to commit and push.

Comment: i tried pushing with SSH before that

Comment: Same error or was it something else?

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this could be that there is a bad HTTPS connection from you to GitHub, you could [use SSH to connect](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to git/https buffer settings.
You can fix this by increasing your git configuration for `postBuffer` from default `1MB` to `500MB`.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```