# send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet when pushing to local git server

Tags: git

For the past couple of days, I have been attempting to push existing repos towards a locally hosted git server (hosted on an http site) to which I was able to push to in the past.
However, I am now unable to do so with the following error.

```
git push
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 534 bytes | 267.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Furthermore, this error only happens to my account. My colleague is currently able to push without any issues. I am also able to execute most other commands including clone and fetch commands.

This error happens whether I push:

- A commit with a single byte of data modified.
- A commit with a large amount of data modified.
- Multiple commits.
- A commit within a fresh repo.

Things I have tried unsuccesfully:

1. [Hossein Kurd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet) which gave little to no helpful information.

```
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

Followed by:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
git clone --depth 1 <repo_URI>
# cd to your newly created directory
git fetch --unshallow 
git pull --all
```

2. [Codemaker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902552/error-when-trying-to-push-local-repository-to-github)

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

3. Checked the remote to make sure it was valid

```
git remote -v
```

4. [DobbyTheElf and TOPKAT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780221/git-push-failing-http-500-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-500-internal) by verifying that I still have over 200 Gb of storage left on the server and by executing the following:

```
git gc
git fsck
```

Comment: You need to look at the logs of the server, since you're getting a 500.  For Apache, this is typically the `error.log` file.  You [should not use `http.postBuffer`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company has a policy where we need to change our passwords every year. So at the beginning of the year, I changed my password.

However, our git accounts are associated with our Microsoft accounts so changing my password *should've* changed my git password in my mind. But it did not.

[Therefore, I had to go into my Credentials Manager in order to remove my previously existing git credentials.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

- Go to Credential Manager

  - in German, it is called: Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung
  - in French, it is called: Gestionnaire d'identification
  - in Polish, it is called: Menedżer poświadczeń
  - in Portuguese, it is called: Gerenciador de Credenciais
  - in Russian, it is called: Диспетчер учётных данных
  - in Spanish, it is called: Administrador de credenciales
- Go to Windows Credentials.
- Delete the entries under Generic Credentials labeled as git. Windows stores quite a variety of credentials in here so don't modify any that you are unwilling to lose.

Then push once and re-enter my new (valid) credentials and all is now functional.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unsatisfactory follow-up, but may be helpful to posterity...
I encountered the same error as OP (also on Windows), but simply deleting saved credential as above did not resolve it for me.
But then I logged out of *Github* and back in, and, voila, the next `git push` worked!

I observe that Github announced [beta support for passkeys](https://github.blog/2023-07-12-introducing-passwordless-authentication-on-github-com/) recently and I had not pushed anything since then.  I didn't sign up for the beta or make any other change on Github, but  *post hoc, ergo propter hoc*?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above and nothing worked. It turned out I had a whole bunch of `.sbar` files (200Mb+, Substance painter, substances). Once I tracked them as git LFS everything worked.

It looks like I was hitting the max file size limit on GitHub.