# git lfs push is throwing "RPC failed" error

Tags: git, git-lfs, tfvc, git-tfs, git-lfs-migrate

I am trying to migrate the repository from **TFVC to Git with History of 4 months** which is a huge data. I am using `git tfs` to clone it from a branch of a repo from TFVC to my local and trying to push it to a empty Git repository by enabling `git lfs` to track the large files and upload.

Steps:
I cloned a TFVC repo branch files with history of 4 months using git tfs clone to my local. then,
git remote add origin '*URL of the empty git repo*' -- empty repo refers to my new git repo created.

Enabled LFS

Tracked the Large files

Made a commit

Migrated the LFS files using `git lfs migrate import --include="*.*" --include-ref=refs/heads/master`

The above successfully converts pre-existing git objects to lfs objects. However, the regular objects still persist in the .git directory. These will be cleaned up eventually by git, but to clean them up right away, run:

```
 git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
         git gc --prune=now
```

& Trying to push it using `git push origin -u -all`

But facing below error:

````
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Migrate whole source code to git (git push)```
````

Comment: Any response here will be much helpful please!!!

Comment: It's a 5xx error so it's the service that has a problem (even if indeed it could be due to the data or parameters sent). Where do you push your code? Github? ADO? Private server? Does it support LFS? Has it been enabled on the server?

Comment: @Philippe Yes I am pushing my code to ADO and I am not sure whether ADO supports LFS, and I think LFS is a moreover client side right? I mean We enable lfs using git ex: git lfs track to track the lfs files. Ok if it needs to be enabled on the server means how to do that?

Comment: In github, it's a paid option so I would like to know but in ADO, it's a free option. So the problem should not come from here. And if you retry now, 23h later, you still has the issue?

Comment: @Philippe Yes after retry also same error.

Comment: Is it helping? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70762741/717372

Comment: @Philippe No sir, actually I am trying to push it to ADO right not to my local. I am pushing from my local to ADO .

Comment: I don't understand your answer regarding the link I provided to you. Did you tried to clean your credentials from the credential manager and provided them again when asked by git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message doesn't come from Git LFS, but from Git itself.  The message "RPC failed; HTTP 503" means that the server side sent a 503 Service Unavailable and Git wasn't able to complete its operation.  Like all 5xx codes, this means that the server encountered an error, and generally the reason and the way to fix it would only be known to the server operator, in this case Azure DevOps.

So in order to fix this, you'd have to ask Azure DevOps what's going wrong and ask them to fix the server so you can push your data.  There's nothing that you can change here or do differently to make this work, since it's a server-side error.