# while push code into aws codeCommit getting this error --> repo : RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54

Tags: git, git-push, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit, git-post-receive

I create a repo  on AWS codecommit over north virginia  and then able to clone it on my local using https url. then i add some of my laravel code, commit it and try to push it over the codecommit. then i got this error

```
iDevOps@swetank01-MacBook-Pro sample-laralab % git push                                      
Enumerating objects: 5379, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5379/5379), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4137/4137), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5379/5379), 296.87 MiB | 300.98 MiB/s, done.
Total 5379 (delta 1004), reused 5371 (delta 1004)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

i even tried creating on other location like on us-east-2. there i got different error like

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/laralab
Cloning into 'laralab'...

repo could not be found
```

I faced this error first i recently implement same CI/CD pipeline using aws without getting got issue inbetween. Any hint Will be Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Related to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4536) it is a problem with your git/curl/libressl or the proxy behind your internet. You can update your git/curl/libressl or try to connect without using proxy.

Otherwise you can also change your git configuration regarding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952683/git-push-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-fatal-the-remote-end-hun/36843260#36843260):

```sh
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: I tried it but still same Error ---> Writing objects: 100% (5379/5379), 296.87 MiB | 279.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 5379 (delta 1004), reused 5371 (delta 1004)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly.. >> Is it  issue from AWS CodeCommit Side i am also pretty much confusdd becasue it working it my older repo and not working with newly created repos

Comment: Did you use a vpn connection or a firewall? Can you increase the buffer size to `1048576000`? Only as a temporary test, can you disable sslVerify with `git config http.sslVerify "false"`?

Comment: I Tried but not working facing same error as facing earlier, now my am checking  for some probability from AWS end may be conf or IAM user

Comment: Do you want to use the `git push` to upload many files that are also relatively large? If so, can you try [this solution](https://github.community/t/error-rpc-failed-curl-55-openssl-ssl-write-ssl-error-zero-return-errno-10053/2226/8)? Can you also try it with ssh?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the inconsistency in the authentication method and the way the repository is cloned.
There are two ways to setup authentication method & cloning a repository.

1. ssh
2. https

If you had setup your authentication mode as ssh, then clone the repository with ssh method only. Doing otherwise(cloning with https) will cause this issue.
I recently faced this issue and I went through a lot of SO posts

1. on increasing the global buffer
2. checking for a larger file size
3. Re-initialize git

These didn't work for me.

All I had to do was delete and re-clone it with ssh method, as the authentication method setup was ssh. Prior to this, I was cloning with https method, which is wrong.
This delete and re-cloning using the same method worked like charm.

Note - Before/After the fix, I was checking in the same piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Works Like a Charm !!!

> `git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true`