# When I want to deploy my node js app to heroku I get the following

Tags: git, heroku

Whenever I want to deploy my node js app on heroku server I get the following erros. I have searched all over the internet for solutions but none. I also did increased my git buffer as suggested here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790215/git-push-to-azure-failing-rpc-failed/39294072#39294072) but I still get the same error

```
λ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 2315, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2203/2203), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2315/2315), 2.26 MiB | 3.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 2315 (delta 482), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku Git - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873032/heroku-git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: I have done that but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS and Git version.

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294072/6309), using a MacOS version was the issue, and the recent [Git for Windows did work](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
That may be because [of a TLS discrepancies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25518086/6309) between the local and remote environment.

Comment: I started Working Sir after installing the New version Updating git